# AVHDX internal format for use with TestDisk

Tags: filesystems, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, avhdx

I can't seem to find any info about this.  What is a HyperV differential AVHDX file format internally like, for the purpose of forensic recovery?

That is: Is it just straight blocks, like dd would output, but with point-in-time metadata in between or in a header?  Or is the main data transcoded in some way?  Or kept in a known internal fs like NTFS or exFAT?  What should I tell TestDisk if I want to open an AVHDX directly, without the rest of its chain?

The original role was a Generation 1 VM.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the spec](http://blogs.technet.com/b/aviraj/archive/2012/04/30/microsoft-download-center-vhdx-format-specification.aspx),

> The VHDX file begins with a fixed-sized header section. After this,
>   non-overlapping objects and free space are intermixed freely in no
>   particular order; the only restriction being that all objects have 1
>   MB alignment within the file. The objects currently defined include
>   the BAT region (also referred to as BAT), the metadata region, header,
>   log, payload blocks and sector bitmap blocks.

But this applies to AVHDX as well:

> VHDX is designed to support 3 types of virtual hard disks; fixed,
>   dynamic and differencing. The logical and physical layout is similar
>   for all 3 types...

However, I don't know enough to know from the rest of the document whether this resembles NTFS or FAT or ReFS or what.

That said, some data is recoverable from a lone AVHDX file with PhotoRec rather than TestDisk (they are bundled together) in GUI mode but also in Expert mode with the CLI version with a 4096 block size or even a 512 block size.